# ZPL - How to set Font size to 9pt?

Tags: label, zpl

How do you use ZPL to change the font size to 9pt?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Onboard fonts are measured in dots, so you have to take into account the DPI of the printer you are targeting, typically 203 DPI, 300 DPI, or 600 DPI.

The [ZPL Manual](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) explains this and gives examples.  See the third and fourth parameters of the ^A command.

Zebra also offers you a free WYSIWYG design tool called [ZebraDesigner Free](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/barcode-printers/zebralink/zebra-designer.html).  You can create a label design and export the ZPL code.  This is a great way to save some time and learn ZPL in the process.

Comment: Can zebraDesigner Export labels as ZPL ? I was not able to find this function

Comment: @prasad , try printing to file.  The prn file will be a text file, and will be ZPL if a ZPL driver has been selected.

Comment: @prasad I used the Labelary WebService to create my labels as PDF and then print them out. http://labelary.com/service.html

Answer (score 10):

```
^CFA,(font size here)

E.g, ^CFA,20
```

This changes the font for the text that comes after this code so it would look something like this

```
^CFA,20
^FO50,340^FD100 Disney Rules^FS
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This will set the font size to 20 dots, not 20 pt. To convert points to dots, use dots=(points/72)*printerDPI. Since the font A is not a scalable font, it can only use integer multiples of its size listed in the manual.